# Assume $A$ is finite and $f$ is a function from $A$ to $A$. Then, f is injective if and only if $ \operatorname{ran} f = A$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Assume the set $A$ is finite and there is a function $f$ from $A$ to $A$. Then, $f$ is injective if and only if $\operatorname{ran} f = A$

I feel lost on how to prove this. I can visualize that since $A$ has a finite number of members that any injective mapping from $A$ to itself would be surjective, i.e. $\operatorname{ran} f = A$. But I have no idea how to go forward formally with a proof. I know the definitions of finite and injectivity, but where would I proceed to from those definitions?

Answer (score 1):

It is always the case that $f(A) \subset A$ and so $|f(A)| \le |A|$.

If $f$ is injective, then $|f(A)| = |A|$ and so $f(A) = A$.

If $f(A) = A$, then $|f(A)| = |A|$ and hence $f(A)$ has $|A|$ distinct elements, and so $f$ is injective.

Answer (score 0):

f is injective iff f is a bijection. Assume it is a bijection onto a proper subset of A. But the cardinality of a proper subset of A is less than the cardinality of A, so this is impossible (by definition). Thus it is a bijection onto A. f is surjective onto A iff it its restriction to a subset of A is a bijection onto A (we can choose one inverse image for each a). But similarly to above, this cannot be a proper subset. Thus f itself is bijective onto A.